# Using bootstrap date-picker - How to do the required validation?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap plugin for date picker. It works fine. I need 2 kind of validation. First one is required field validation and second specified date won't accept. Can anyone help on this? Even I'm beginner for j query. Advance appreciate for your help.

**Jquery Code:**

```
$(function () {
  window.prettyPrint && prettyPrint();
  $('#ContentSection_txtFromDate, #ContentSection_txtToDate').datepicker({
     format: 'mm-dd-yyyy'
 });
```

**Aspx code**

```
      <div>
            <p>
                <asp:Label ID="lblEndingTimeStamp" runat="server" Text="<span>*</span> Ending Time Stamp"
                        AssociatedControlID="ddlEndingTimeStamp"></asp:Label>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlEndingTimeStamp" runat="server">
                        <asp:ListItem Value="0">23:59:59</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblToDate" runat="server" Text="<span>*</span> To Date" AssociatedControlID="txtToDate"></asp:Label><asp:TextBox
                        ID="txtToDate" runat="server" value="MM/DD/YYYY" onfocus="if(this.value == 'MM/DD/YYYY')this.value='';"
                        onblur="if(this.value =='')this.value='MM/DD/YYYY';"></asp:TextBox></p>

            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are doing some type of form submission, letting `trip-picker` be the `<form>` id, the following would catch unfilled fields and invalid date combinations:

```
$('#trip-picker').submit(function() {
  var fromDate = $('#ContentSection_txtFromDate').val(),
      toDate = $('#ContentSection_txtFromDate').val();

  if (!fromDate || !toDate) {
    alert("both dates required!");
    return false;
  } else if (Date.parse(fromDate) > Date.parse(toDate)) {
    alert("departure date must precede return date!");
    return false;
  }

});
```